# Check if variable been initialized in PHP

Tags: php, variable-declaration

I have been implementing a Wordpress plugin and I faced a problem with finding out if a variable has been declared or not.

Let's say I have a model named `Hello`; this model has 2 variables as `hello_id` and `hello_name`.

In the database we have table named `hello` with 3 columns as `hello_id`, `hello_name` , `hello_status`.

I would like to check if a variable has been declared and, if it has, set a value.

```
abstract class MasterModel {
    protected function setModelData($data)
    {
        foreach($data as $key=>$value){
            if(isset($this->{$key})){ // need to check if such class variable declared
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Hello extends MasterModel{
    public $hello_id;
    public $hello_name;
    function __construct($hello_id = null)
    {
        if ($hello_id != null){
            $this->hello_id = $hello_id;
            $result = $wpdb->get_row(
                "SELECT * FROM hello WHERE hello_id = $hello_id"
            , ARRAY_A);
            $this->setModelData($data);
       } 
    }
}
```

The main reason why I am doing this is to make my code expandable in the future. For example I might not use some fields from the database but in future I might need them.

Comment: isnt isset() working ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use several options

```
//this will return true if $someVarName exists and it's not null
if(isset($this->{$someVarName})){
//do your stuff
}
```

you can also check if [property exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) and if it doesn't add it to the class.

property_exists returns true even if value is null

```
if(!property_exists($this,"myVar")){
    $this->{"myVar"} = " data.."
}
```

Comment: thanks, property_exists($key,$value) worked out like a charm.

Comment: On PHP 7.4 if a variable has no value at all, property_exists returns true. Prior to 7.4 the default value of properties was null. Thats no longer the case.

Answer (score 4):

Use isset http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

```php
if(isset($var)){

//do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Talking about a nullable class property, to check if it has been initialized:

```php
class MyClass {
  public ?MyType $my_property;
  public \ReflectionProperty $rp;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->rp = new \ReflectionProperty(self::class, 'my_property');
  }

  public function myMethod()
  {
    if (!$this->rp->isInitialized($this)) {
      // Do stuff when my_property has never been initialized
    }
  }
}
```

This is useful when creating a caching system where the value can be null.

Comment: This answer is a bit more "expensive" but it's the correct way to know the difference between a property that exists but has not been assigned *anything* yet. `isset()`, `empty()` etc. don't know the difference between "initialized" and `null`, and whether initialized or not, `property_exists()` will be `true` whether it's initialized or not.